# Retrieve all relating nodes, Cypher query in Neo4jClient .NET

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4jclient

I have a method that performs a Cypher query that I would like return all nodes and their names that have a relationship with a node specified(64) in the query:

```
start n = node(64) match (n)--(x) return x.Name;
```

Now when I try and do this in my code it does not want to work. Here is my method:

```
public string GetAllFirstLevelRelatives(long NodeId)
{

    string QueryResult = null;

    try
    {
        var query = client_connection
            .Cypher
            .Start(NodeId, client_connection.RootNode)
            .Match(NodeId, "--(x)")
            .Return<Node<GraphNode>>("(x).name");

        QueryResult = query.Results.ToString();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {

    }
    return QueryResult;
}
```

I would like this query to return the names.

Could anyone help me please?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This query:

```
start n = node(64) match n--x return x.Name;
```

Should be written in C# as:

```
var query = graphClient
    .Cypher
    .Start("n", node)           // START n=node(123)
    .Match("n--x")              // MATCH n--x
    .Return<string>("x.Name");  // RETURN x.Name
```

There were a few problems with the sample code you provided:

1. There will likely be multiple nodes, but your method was only returning a single `string` result. Calling `Results.ToString()` is going to return something like `"System.Collections.IEnumberable<string>"` instead of the actual results.
2. You should avoid passing node ids around as `long`s. Doing so encourages you to use the raw numbers, which you shouldn't be doing. Instead, use `NodeReference`. Any query that you run with Neo4jClient will give you a `NodeReference` object back. Use this to run your next query. To start your very first query, we supply `IGraphClient.RootNode`. You basically never need to touch node ids.
3. Wrapping any .NET code in a `try {} catch {}` block where the `catch` section is empty is **always** a big no-no. Please do not write this in any code, ever. :)
4. `x.Name` is likely a string, but then you were calling this with `.Return<Node<GraphNode>>`. This basically says "load `x.Name` (a string) but give it back to me as a `Node<GraphNode>`". That doesn't make a lot of sense. You need to match the types.

Combining the query I wrote above, and those points, this is what your method should look like:

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetAllFirstLevelRelatives(NodeReference node)
{
    var query = graphClient
        .Cypher
        .Start("n", node)           // START n=node(123)
        .Match("n--x")              // MATCH n--x
        .Return<string>("x.name");  // RETURN x.name

    return query.Results.ToList();
}
```

To improve this further, you should take advantage of our type system. What is "`x`" in your query? Let's imagine it's a movie.

You should create a class that describes what a movie node contains:

```
public class Movie
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

That class should be a 'POCO' (plain old class object) which means it should only have basic properties on it, and not methods or logic.

Then, use this type information in your query:

```
public IEnumerable<Movie> GetAllRelatedMovies(NodeReference node)
{
    var query = graphClient
        .Cypher
        .Start("n", node)
        .Match("n--movie")
        .Return<Movie>("movie");

    return query.Results.ToList();
}
```

Now you have a list of movies, instead of just a list of strings. It's quite unlikely that you'd just want the name of the movies, so this way you get access to all of the properties.